# Flash Media Server, test RTMP stream from Flash Builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder, rtmp, flash-media-server

I have a server with RTMP service but when I publish the SWF from Flash Builder it says stream not found. Server is on the Virtual Machine, so I access it through IP. If I do the same from Flash IDE (ctrl ENTER) it works fine. I know it has something to do with security but how can I actually test the app then.

Answer (score 1):

if an swf from local filesystem tries to access a location on the web it's blocked by default. You can manage this behaviour from http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html 
or maybe you have `<use-network>false</use-network>` in your flex config

Comment: How do I manage that behaviour on that site? What do I have to do? It's not a Flex project it's an AS project.

Comment: @ Murgh : you need to add a location where your swf file is stored locally and give the permission to all swf files from there connect the internet